# Articles are text-only in any "Category" instead of HTML

Tags: posts, categories, html

I run a Wordpress blog at http://toile.reinom.com/ and a lot of articles are using HTML codes (mainly `<h*>`, `<p>`, `<a>` and `<figure>`). Those tags are correctly displayed on the homepage and inside any blog post.

But when you browse a category (as http://toile.reinom.com/category/concevoir/concevoir-general/ ), then the articles are texts only. Same when you're doing some research on the blog.

I'm okay having text-only version when doing a research (since WP displays the part of the article where the words were found), but how can I have the HTML version of the articles on the categories? Or is it a plugin that have broken that feature (aka, if WP actually shows HTML in categories, then my theme or plugins have broken it)?

Comment: Isn't your theme just using `the_excerpt()` instead of `the_content()` in the `category.php`/`archive.php` theme files?

Comment: @birgire That's exactly the problem (I've understood it exactly when you've commented ^^). If you make it an answer, I'll accept it right away.

Comment: Good to hear you found the reason for this, note that you can also accept your own answer if you want to take us through your path of discovery ;-)

Comment: @birgire Okay, it will be acceptable in 2 days. I feel schizophrenic every time I accept my own answers x)

Comment: *I feel schizophrenic every time I accept my own answers*. No need feel that way. It is encouraged to answer your own questions if you reach a viable solution ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The theme uses `the_excerpt()` instead of `the_content()`**.

I had created a child theme before (so I don't modify the source theme directly: only the child one), so I only had to copy/paste the PHP file (`archive.php`) from source theme to child theme, and change `the_excerpt()` for `the_content( __( 'Read more &#8250;', 'my-domain' ) );`